# is it halal to work on a web application that finds jobs

Tags: halal-haram, halal-certification

asssalamu alaikom everyone 
i want to know if it is halal to work on a web application that allows its users to post job offers or post job services like for example a programmer can offer their skills to get hired by a company , or a recruiter can post a job offer to hire someone . but what's crossing my mind is that this app can be used to look for any kind of jobs like for example a bartender can search for a job or a bar owner can look for bartenders etc .
bottom line is that it could be used for good and for evil depending on what the user is looking for

thank you in advance.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].